# Exclude UIButton's label from all UILabels in a UIView's subview

Tags: ios, swift

I am wanting to change all the UILabel's in my UIViews color on the fly.

I grab all the UIViews via:

```
extension UIView {

    func subViews<T : UIView>(type : T.Type) -> [T]{
        var all = [T]()
        for view in self.subviews {
            if let aView = view as? T{
                all.append(aView)
            }
        }
        return all
    }

    func allSubViewsOf<T : UIView>(type : T.Type) -> [T]{
        var all = [T]()
        func getSubview(view: UIView) {
            if let aView = view as? T{
                all.append(aView)
            }
            guard view.subviews.count>0 else { return }
            view.subviews.forEach{ getSubview(view: $0) }
        }
        getSubview(view: self)
        return all
    }
}
```

Which works fine, unless there is a UIButton in the UIView, then it grabs the UIButton's label as well.

```
    let allLabels = view.allSubViewsOf(type: UILabel.self)
    changeColor(allLabels)
```

Change Color:

```
  fileprivate func changeColor(_ objects: [UILabel]) {
        for label in objects {
            print("Superview: \(type(of: label.superview))")
            label.textColor = isNight ? .white : .black
        }
    }
```

I have tried comparing the `label.superview.isDescendant(of:  UIButton.self)` but the superview is UIView.

I am at a loss.

How can I exclude the UIButton's Label?

Comment: When you do: `if let aView = view as? T`, you might not want to to keep it if it's `UIButton`, and so do not iterate its subviews?

Comment: You should consider using the [appearance apis](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiappearance) instead

Comment: I have a lot of custom controls too so the appearance apis are used for my generic stuff

Answer (score 1):

I ended up creating a second function that takes another type to exclude

```
func allSubViewsOf<K : UIView, V: UIView>(type : K.Type, excluding: V.Type ) -> [K]{
        var all = [K]()
        func getSubview(view: UIView) {
            guard !(view is V) else { return }
            if let aView = view as? K{
                all.append(aView)
            }
            guard view.subviews.count>0 else { return }
            view.subviews.forEach{ getSubview(view: $0) }
        }
        getSubview(view: self)
        return all
    }
```

Comment: You might need an array of types not to include. Many UI controls contain internal labels, not just UIButton. BTW - see my answer for a much simpler way to implement your algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

As you iterate each subview, check if the subview is a `UIButton`. It it is, skip it.

Also, your recursive algorithm can be written much simpler. For example:

```
extension UIView {
    func allSubViewsOf<T : UIView>(type : T.Type) -> [T]{
        guard !(self is UIButton) else { return [] }

        var all = [T]()

        for view in subviews {
            if let tview = view as? T {
                all.append(tview)
            } else {
                all.append(contentsOf: view.allSubViewsOf(type: type))
            }
        }

        return all
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that there may be other controls that contain an internal `UILabel` so you may need to check for more than `UIButton`.

Answer (score 0):

How about **filter** with **isKind**?

Example:

```
let subviewLabels = view.subviews.filter({$0.isKind(of: UILabel.self)})
```

In this case we will fetch all `UILabel` from our view.

Answer (score 0):

You can assign each label a `tag`, which is an integer value that you can use to identify the label.

For example, you can assign `UILabel.tag` value to `1` for only the labels you would like the color to change. However, when you declare your labels you will need to set the tag values. I coded a function for you that recursively iterates through the subviews of a view and returns an array of all of the `UILabel`'s with a `tag` of 1:

```
// function that recursively returns all of the labels in a view's subviews with a tag equal to 1
func getAllLabelsOf(view: UIView) -> [UILabel] {
    var labels = [UILabel]()
    for subview in view.subviews {
        if let label = subview as? UILabel {
            // only get labels with tags equal to one
            if label.tag == 1 {
                 labels.append(label)
            }
        }
        // recursively get all subviews Labels
        let recursiveLabels = getAllLabelsOf(view: subview)
        labels = labels + recursiveLabels
    }
    return labels
}
```